# How do you deny access to a specific directory when the directory is already part of RewriteCond rule and doesn't event exist?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security

I've been searching and testing as many different ways to do this as I can but nothing seems to be working. In a nut shell, I'm streaming audio, but the path is obfuscated via a rewritecond rule. I don't want direct access via the browser to the streaming file, but PHP still needs access to the file to stream it. Here is the streaming URL:

```
www.test.com/audio/32478576
```

The "audio" directory doesn't exist. I'm using .htaccess to redirect it to the streaming script. Here are the .htaccess bits:

```
RewriteRule ^/?audio/([\d]+)/?$ serve.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

All that works great. So, I figured that all that would be needed to deny access to the file would be to add the following to my .htaccss file:

```
<Files ~ "audio/">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

That didn't work. I was still able to get the audio to stream directly from the browser.

Perhaps this is not possible - trying to do what I want it to do. What am I missing? .htaccess is not my strength by any means, but I still think it's possible. I just don't have the right code or things in the right order, perhaps. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

There may be something wrong with my server setup. I did a basic test with the following Rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)test.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule test\.php$ - [F]
```

But I still had direct access to the test.php file. But - I shouldn't, right? Perhaps something is incorrectly set on my server?

Answer (score 0):

`<directory>` and `<files>` directives apply to the filesystem. Since /audio directory does not exist, the `<Files ~ "audio/">` has no effect.
`<Location>` directive applies to Urls, and may work.
In a different approach, if Apache version is 2.4, it can be done as it is described in this documentation page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html.

Comment: I looked in the <Location> declaration, but it looks like (if I read it right) that <Location> is no allowed in .htaccess - only httpd.conf. I am using Apache 2.4, and looked at the Access Control bits, but I'm afraid I was not able to understand it fully.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to prevent serve.php from being accessed outside your domain test.com. If so then, the HTTP_REFERRER should be a url containing test.com.

The HTTP_REFERRER can be checked from htaccess using code that prevents hot linking of media files. This link: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644230/prevent-hotlinking-with-a-htaccess-file describes how to prevent hot linking of media files. The code given in the link can be modified to prevent hot linking of your serve.php file. The following code should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)test.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule audio/.+$ - [F]
```

Comment: Yes and no. Theoretically, serve.php would never be seen by the end user. only http://www.test.com/audio/32478576 would be seen, as .htaccess translates that to server.php?id=32478576. So denying access to server.php would probably be a secondary this, but denying access to the /audio directory would be be the main thing. Again, the /audio/ directory does not exist. It's just a placeholder for .htaccess to hook into so it can actually point to serve.php.

Comment: I updated the example so now it blocks the files in the audio directory if the http referrer is not test.com

Comment: Thanks for the update on your code. Gave it a try, but still had access. I just updated my original post with a test. Take a look at my update. Perhaps that's why your suggestions are not working.